# How to draw additional absciss on grid?

Tags: mpandroidchart, ios-charts

I'm using MPAndroidCharts and ios-charts for my apps. [I need additional absciss at custom y!=0 to be drawed. And it would be great if points above that level will painted to custom color.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0nSI.jpg)

How to realize that?

Comment: can you make some screenshot and draw there some example of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use limit line as additional line, smth like this:

```
ChartLimitLine *ll1 = [[ChartLimitLine alloc] initWithLimit:YOUR_NUMBER label:@""];
ll1.lineColor = [UIColor greenColor];
ll1.lineWidth = 1.0;
```

To change circle colors, you need to modify `private func drawCircles(context context: CGContext)` method in `LineChartRenderer`.

There's a for-loop with line:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, dataSet.getCircleColor(j)!.CGColor)
```

You can change it to smth like:

```
if e.value > YOUR_VALUE {
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor)
}
else {
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, dataSet.getCircleColor(j)!.CGColor)
}
```

[image: And will be smth like this:]